# What's the rule of method declare in Obj-c? Could I use a method without declaration directly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.4

In Xcode4.4, I found I can use a method define in .m file directly without declaration in .h head file or .m file.

what's the rule of method declaration in Obj-c?
Could I use a method without declaration in head file?

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a method in the header file, then other classes will be able to access that method.

Comment: And if you don't declare it in your header, other classes will not be able to use that method.

Comment: But the class itself can always use that method.

Comment: If you declare the prototype in the .m file, you get a private method.

Comment: The compiler will compain (and, under ARC, fail), but you _can_ send a message for an undeclared method, or use `performSelector:` and it will succeed at runtime.

Comment: I don't declare the method neither in head file nor in .m file

Answer (score 0):

You import headers whenever you want to use the methods declared in the headers.

So if you have created a class called `ObjectA` then to be able to use the methods you have declared in `ObjectA.h` you need to import it `#import "ObjectA.h"`.

You usually only need to do the imports in your implementation `.m` files. If you need it in your header file you can use the `@class` annotation like this:

```
@class ObjectA
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) ObjectA *objectA;
```